# How do I deviate backtracking?

Tags: prolog, backtracking

I have 3, 4 rules like this:

```
pagaTot(X,Acc,PagaMens):-   giorno(d(X,_,14),[iniziato(I,_,_),_,ListServ|L]),!,
                            length(ListaServ,N),N<2,
                            member(finito(F),L),
                            I>=6, F=<24,
                            I1 is round(I)+round((I-round(I))*100)/60,
                            F1 is round(F)+round((F-round(F))*100)/60,
                            OreTot is F1-I1,
                            OreTot =<8,
                            Paga is (F1-I1)*6,
                            Acc1 is Paga+Acc,X1 is X+1,
                            pagaTot(X1,Acc1,PagaMens).



pagaTot(X,Acc,PagaMens):-   giorno(d(X,_,14),[iniziato(I,_,_),_,ListServ|L]),!,
                        length(ListaServ,N),N<2,
                        member(finito(F),L),
                        I>=6, F=<24,
                        I1 is round(I)+round((I-round(I))*100)/60,
                        F1 is round(F)+round((F-round(F))*100)/60,
                        OreTot is F1-I1,
                        OreTot >8,
                        OreDa7 is OreTot-8,
                        OreDa6 is OreTot-OreDa7, 
                        Paga is OreDa6*6+OreDa7*7,
                        Acc1 is Paga+Acc,X1 is X+1,
                        pagaTot(X1,Acc1,PagaMens).
```

When the system finds that it's a wrong choice it backtracks. I don't want it to check again for other choices in the first subgoal - 'giorno(d(...'. It better goes strait to the next 'pagaTot(X...' rule this way will be more efficient by about 3, 4 calls for each rule. I tried to put '!' at the end of the first subgoal _,ListServ|L)**,!,** but this cut would not let it go for the next rule. It stops with a total fail.
I have no other idea where should this cut be put. Is there a solution?

Comment: The giorno is a functor of a long structure from where I calculate various things. And there are at list 4 or 5 choice points where the calculation should be past to another pagaTot :- rule when the chosen one can not do it.

Answer (score 0):

I would factorize the common part, then with an if/then/else discriminate the change point:

```
pagaTot(X,Acc,PagaMens):- giorno(d(X,_,14),[iniziato(I,_,_),_,ListServ|L]),
                        length(ListaServ,N),N<2,
                        member(finito(F),L),
                        I>=6, F=<24,
                        I1 is round(I)+round((I-round(I))*100)/60,
                        F1 is round(F)+round((F-round(F))*100)/60,
                        OreTot is F1-I1,
                        (  OreTot =<8
                        -> Paga is (F1-I1)*6
                        ;  OreDa7 is OreTot-8,
                           OreDa6 is OreTot-OreDa7, 
                           Paga is OreDa6*6+OreDa7*7
                        ),
                        Acc1 is Paga+Acc,X1 is X+1
                        pagaTot(X1,Acc1,PagaMens).
```

Hope I didn't do any mistake on cut'n'paste...

Comment: While working on that staff I thought many times about if, then, else. It's too bad I never used those operators. I will have to study some to understand your suggestion. Thanks any way!